# Variables used in my method are showing errors and are unresolved

Tags: java, eclipse, syntax-error

So, i was using some variables in my methods but I get errors and I dont know how to fix this heres my code from my first class:

import java.util.Scanner;

```
public class Gerbilfood {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gerbil[] gerbil;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please input how many types of food items the gerbils eat as an integer");
        String n0 = scanner.nextLine();
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(n0);
        String[] food = new String[n1];

        for (int i = 0; i < n1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a food name");

            String n2 = scanner.nextLine();
            food[i] = n2;
            int[] maximum = new int[n1];

            System.out.println("Please enter maximum amount of food per day");
            String n33 = scanner.nextLine();
            int n3 = Integer.parseInt(n33);
            maximum[i] = n3;
        }

        System.out.println("Please enter in the number of gerbils in the lab");
        String n73 = scanner.nextLine();
        int n4 = Integer.parseInt(n73);
        gerbil = new Gerbil[n4];

        int[] combo = new int[n4];
        String[] ids = new String[n4];
        for (int i = 0; i < n4; i++) {
            Gerbil g = new Gerbil(n1);

            System.out.println("Please enter in the lab id for each gerbil");
            String n5 = scanner.nextLine();
            g.setId(n5);

            //ids[i] = n5;

            //String[] names = new String[n4];

            System.out.println("Please enter in the name of each gerbil");
            String n6 = scanner.nextLine(); // gerbil name
            g.setName(n6);

            String[] amountfood = new String[n1];
            for (int j = 0; j < n1; j++) {
                System.out.println("how much of" + food[j] + "did the gerbil eat");
                String n8 = scanner.nextLine();
                amountfood[i] = n8;
            }
            String[] bite = new String[n4];
            System.out.println("Does this Gerbil bite? Enter True or False");
            String n77 = scanner.nextLine();
            bite[i] = n77;

            String[]escape = new String[n4];
            System.out.println("Does this Gerbil escape? Enter True or False");
            String n89 = scanner.nextLine();
            escape[i] = n89;
        }

        System.out.println("What information would you like to know?");
        String n55 = scanner.nextLine();

        String n33 = "search";
        String n34 = "average";
        String n35 = "restart";
        String n36 = "quit";

        if(n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n34)) {
            System.out.println(averagefood());
        } else {
            if(n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n33)) {
                System.out.println("Please type the lab id of the gerbil you wish to search for");
                String n87 = scanner.nextLine();

                System.out.println();
        } else {
            if (n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n35)) {
                //go back to beginning of program
            } else {
                if (n55.equalsIgnoreCase(n36)) {
                    System.exit(0);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("ERROR");
                }
            }
        }
    }               
}

public static int averagefood(int n4, int n3, int n8) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n4; i++) {
        long percent = Math.round(n8 * 100.0 / n3);

        return averagefood(newName, newId, percent);
    }
}

public static int searchForGerbil() {
    n87 = setId;        
    return 0;
    // return (new Gerbil[i]
```

and heres the code from my second class:

```
public class Gerbil {
    private String id;
    private String name;
    private int[] amountfood;
    //private int numbergerbils;
    //private int maxfood;

    private boolean escape;
    private boolean bite;

    public Gerbil(String n5, String n6, int numOfFood, boolean newEscape, boolean newBite) {
        id = n5;
        name = n6;
        amountfood = new int[numOfFood];
        escape = newEscape;
        bite = newBite;
    }

    public Gerbil(int numOfFood) {
        amountfood = new int[numOfFood];
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setId(String newId) {
        id = newId;
    }

    public void setName(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the stacktrace that you got.

Comment: you mean the error message?

Comment: Yes, the stacktrace is the error message + the lines of code that called it.
Btw, do you get your variable names from a random number generator?

Comment: So what is the error that you received?

Comment: no i didnt use the generator and it says next to System.out.println(averagefood()); The method averagefood(int, int, int) in the type Gerbilfood is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: and it says Multiple markers at this line
 - getName cannot be resolved to a variable
 - Syntax error on token "return", Name expected after 
  this token
 - getId cannot be resolved to a variable
 - newId cannot be resolved to a variable
 - newName cannot be resolved to a variable                              it says that next to return averagefood(newName, newId, percent);

Answer (score 0):

> it says next to System.out.println(averagefood()); The method
>   averagefood(int, int, int) in the type Gerbilfood is not applicable
>   for the arguments ()

If you check your code your function definition requires three arguments and you have not passed any.

> getName cannot be resolved to a variable

This is a function in class Gerbil and hence needs to be called as follows:
Gerbil gb = new Gerbil();
gb.getName();

> Syntax error on token "return", Name expected after this token - getId
>   cannot be resolved to a variable - newId cannot be resolved to a
>   variable - newName cannot be resolved to a variable it says that next
>   to return averagefood(newName, newId, percent);

None of these variables have been defined in class Gerbilfood. What values are you expecting to pass using these variables?

Comment: I am expecting to pass the values that the user inputs which are defined by the variables I have in my main class

Comment: I posted it though in my original posting of my question